# What will be an efficient joint clustering solution to this problem?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, clustering

There is a system with $S$ transmitters/service points, $U$ subscribers/users.
The link quality/gain between any transmitter indexed by $s$ and a user indexed with $u$ is denoted by $h_{u,s}$.
Any transmitter can either serve the user or act an an interferer if it is not serving.

Now, we have a predefined number of groups/clusters, defined as $G$.

For a given cluster, all the transmitters in the cluster serve all the users in that cluster, but act an interferer to the users in other clusters.

What will be an optimal or near optimal/heauristic clustering solution for this problem?

The objective is to optimise the summation of service quality of all the users. The service quality of a given user is defined by the ratio of serving signal to the interfering signal. Serving signal is the summation of signals from the transmitters in user's own group and interfering signal is the summation of signals from the transmitters in other groups.

An MI(N)LP formulation should be avoided as this will be very difficult to solve for large system. And I have a large system.

Comment: In your third paragraph, did you mean $G$ clusters rather than $M$ clusters?

Comment: For reference, a linearizable MINLP formulation is [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/6031/500).

Comment: @prubin, Yes. I have corrected the typo. Please suggest me a heuristic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support Rob Pratt's linearized MIP formulation (his answer to the question posted on OR SE). That said, the problem is definitely amenable to heuristic solutions. Since there are no limits on the number of users in a group, and since the objective function is additive (meaning the quality of service for one user is unaffected by the assignment of other users), for a given clustering of transmitters you can just compute the service quality for each individual user and each group and assign the user to the group that maximizes service quality. That puts the focus on clustering the transmitters.

Now suppose you can cook up a measure of the interference between transmitters in different groups. If the issue here is radio interference, that should be pretty straightforward, and presumably would be based on some combination of distance between transmitters, signal power and maybe frequency assignment. Let's call that measure $\delta_{s,s'}$ for transmitters $s < s'$. You can cluster transmitters so as to minimize the sum of the $\delta$ values for pairs of transmitters in different clusters, or to maximize the sum of the $\delta$ values for pairs in the same cluster (under the assumption that being in the same cluster will mitigate the interference), or some other measure. There are a variety of clustering algorithms in the literature, or you can do it using a MIP model (which will be smaller than Rob's model since it does not include the users). Once you have a clustering of the transmitters, assign each user to that user's best cluster.

**Update**: I put this to the test with a small test problem (100 users, 20 servers, 4 clusters), using a random key genetic algorithm. The GA does not find the optimal solution. Whether the solution is good enough, and whether it scales acceptably, are left to the reader as an exercise. :-) I coded it in R. The full description and code are in an [R notebook](https://rubin.msu.domains/blog/joint_clustering.nb.html).

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and your efforts to code it. Is your answer still valid if the number of groups can be <=G?

Comment: Yes. In particular, the GA can easily be adapted to allowing fewer than $G$ groups: you just allow dividers to appear consecutively, creating empty groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please comment of the time/computational complexity of this GA, for example, with your current simulation setup.

Comment: The GA is a random algorithm, and execution time depends on a number of parameters (population size, number of generations run, ...), so I cannot make any valid generalizations on runtime. For the simulation experiment described in my answer, the GA ended up running 100 generations (but got the best solution it found somewhere around 80 generations), which took about 70 seconds on my desktop PC.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried to solve Rob Pratt's approach. For even a small problem, the solver is taking huge amount of time. I do not have experience with R, GA and do not have access to GA toolbox either. As you mentioned we can just put focus on clustering of transmitters and the model would be smaller. Would you please generate such mip model. I would prefer that the number of groups is also a variable.

Comment: you devised the GA algorithm for the relation I mentioned, $U>S>G$. $S>G$ always holds. However, sometimes we can have $U\le S$. Is you approach still valid?

Comment: The GA approach does not require that $U$ be greater than (or equal to) $S$.

Comment: thanks, yes I could run it in R. It solves in reasonable time. I need  to evaluate the performance now. You mentioned that I can formulate the clustering of transmitters as MIP. Would you please provide me the MIP so that I can compare the performance with the GA you wrote.

Comment: the GA algorithm you suggested always provide $G$ clusters. Also, some clusters have no users!

Comment: You said the problem specifies the number $G$ of clusters, so yes, the GA provides $G$ clusters.  If a cluster has no users, it's because every user is better off in some other cluster. That means the servers in the user-free cluster can be decommissioned or repurposed. If you really need $G$ clusters with at least one user in each cluster, you can adjust the GA solution by choosing a "sacrificial goat" for each empty cluster, moving to the empty cluster the user who suffers the least as a result.

Comment: Where RRU = ...?

Comment: thanks for your comments. I also notice that the clustered service points are scattered. How can we constrain the service points belonging to any clusters are neighbours to each other, or at least neighbour to its neighbour.? –